# How to compute the vertices for a 3D polyline extrusion?

Tags: c#, 3d, mesh, polyline

I have a polyline composed of multiple line segments. The line is very complex and squiggles all over the place in 3D, so for simplicity's sake let's say it looks something like this

[image: line]

I want to render it in 3D. Currently, I do a very simple process where I just generate a cylinder for each segment:

[image: line with extruded segments]

This is decent, but looks bad where the line changes direction. It is also wasteful - each of the direction changes requires twices as many vertices as is strictly necessary. I would be much happier with an approach that generated shapes like this:

[image: line with a single extruded polycylinder]

At first I didn't think it would be too hard, but the more I've worked on it the more I've found it to be surprisingly nontrivial. I'm working in C#, and if this were in 2D I would just use [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php), but I can't find any libraries or resources for how to solve this problem in 3D. It's okay if the solution isn't always perfect or sometimes leads to self-intersections or things of that nature. Anyone have any guidance?

Comment: maybe this ? https://github.com/mattdesl/extrude-polyline

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=extrude&type=Repositories

Comment: Can you show some of the code on how the line segments are defined and how the geometry of each cylinder is calculated.

Comment: @AndréPopovitch that is pretty smart code although the resulting cylinder is a mesh of extruded n-gon inscribed to the cylinder. The next step would be an additional loop that extends/trims the mesh so that two segments share nodes. The complication here is the orientation of the n-gon is random (see `normal` vector), so two consecutive "cylinders" would be at an arbitrary angle to each other making the intersection of the two n-gons so much more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this site](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_cylinder.html#pipe) which had an elegant solution. Starting with some points around the first line segment making up your polyline, you compute the intersection of the line parallel to the current segment that passes through each point and the plane formed by the intersection of the two current line segments.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So in a mathematical sense, the intersection of two cylinders is an ellipse. If I give you where the semi-major axis point on the ellipse is and the semi-minor axis you could calculate any number (like `numsides`) nodes on the ellipse.

Take the node connecting two segments located at a point **p** and define the two vectors of the ellipse as follows. **a** is the semi-major axis and **b** is the semi-minor axis

[image: fig1]

Each joining line segment has unit directions vectors **e_1** and **e_2** and the cylinder has radius **R**.

Then the intersection ellipse would be defined from the vectors **a** and **b**:

[image: fig2]

Then find a point **c** around the ellipse use the following parameterization with `t = 0..1`

[image: fig3]

Here is some `C#` code that calculates `numsides` points around the ellipse

```
// Vectors p, a, b defined
for(int i=0; i<numsides; i++)
{
    double t = (1.0*i)/numsides
    Vector c = p + a*Math.Cos(2*Math.PI*t) + b*Math.Sin(2*Math.PI*t)
    // use/store c as needed for the mesh generation
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Since posting this question I came across this link: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_cylinder.html#pipe , which I think is a similar approach (computing the intersection of each line of the prism with the plane where the two cylinders should meet). I think your solution will work better, though, I'm going to try implementing it right now and mark it as solved once I do